# How do I print out the remaning data after each pass?

Tags: java, binary-search

I was working on this problem for school

> "Write a binary search program that looks for the following 3 values
>   74, 35, 62 (Yes, I know...) )in the supplied data set. Your
>   application should print out the remaining data after each pass.  Data
>   set: 23 27 29 31 35 39 40 41 52 66 71 74 75 90 99"

Currently, I coded up to the part where I find the location of the look for value. I just don't know how to print out the remaining data after each pass. Please help.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class BinarySearchTracing{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int[] d = {23, 27, 29, 31, 35, 39, 40, 41, 52, 66, 71, 74, 75, 90, 99};
    int start = 0;
    int middle = 0;
    int end = d.length - 1;
    int location = -1;
    boolean found = false;

    System.out.println("Enter the look for value: ");
    int lookfor = scan.nextInt();
    scan.close();

    while(start <= end && found == false) {
        middle = (start + end) / 2;
        if(d[middle] == lookfor) {
            found = true;
            location = middle;
        }
        else if(d[middle] < lookfor) {
            start = middle + 1;
        }
        else {
            end = middle - 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(location);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the expected result that you want to achieve.

Comment: Ignore the binary search part of the problem. Take a step and think about how you print out the values of `d`.

Comment: The result after the first pass should be:

41, 52, 66, 71, 74, 75, 90, 99

Answer (score 0):

To print subarray of the given array between two indexes, you may use one of the [following methods](https://www.techiedelight.com/get-subarray-array-specified-indexes-java/):

- Arrays.copyOfRange
- System.arraycopy, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is meaningless doing this by binary search but since you have to do it I can give you one possible way,

After you found the location, you will have to iterate through the array and build a string using string builder by skipping only the location you found via binary search

If you have to remove an item from the array once it's been searched for, then it's better to create a new array with the remaining values and use `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(new array))`